# Replace value from multi-dimensional array

Tags: ios, swift

I have an array made from a struct that holds multiple arrays and when trying to replace a value within the subarray I am met with an error:

> Fatal error: Index out of range

```
  struct Main {
  var city: String
  var pop: Int
  var color: String
}

class Home {
    
var mainArray = [[Main]]()

func update() {
    let data = Main(city: "SF", pop: 2, color: "orange")
    mainArray.append(data)
    
    for var subArray in mainArray {
        for var i in subArray {
          var newCity = "SB"
          
           i.city = newCity
           subArray[0].city = i.city
       }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The line starting with `var mainArray` is not valid Swift code. Please update your question with the actual code you're using.

Comment: Made an update. Hope that helps

Comment: `mainArray.append(data)` still doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will never work because due to value semantics you are going to modify a copy of the array and subarray.

You have to modify always the original array directly, something like this

```
struct Main {
  var city: String
  var pop: Int
  var color: String
}

var mainArray = [[Main(city: "SF", pop: 1, color: "blue")], [Main(city: "NYC", pop: 2, color: "white")]]

for (index,  subArray) in mainArray.enumerated() {
    for (subIndex, _) in subArray.enumerated() {
        let newCity = "SB"
        mainArray[index][subIndex].city = newCity
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I wanted to indeed modify the original array and was stuck figuring out how but this answer was helpful with finding a solution.